# Number of meetings of $2$ cars starting from opposite ends of a road

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, speed, distance

**Question:**

> $2$ cars travelling at $108,75$ kmph respectively, start from the opposite ends of a $90$ km straight road. Travelling back and forth continuously for $10$ hours, how many times do the $2$ cars meet? [No loss of time at the turns]

**My Approach:**

> Time to meet for the first time = $\left(\frac{90}{108+75}\right)$ hours and for any subsequent meeting, they'll take $2\times\left(\frac{90}{108+75}\right)$ hours. 
> So, for the $n^{th}$ meeting they 'll take a total of $\frac{(2n-1)90}{183}$ hours which should be less than $10$ and solving:
> $$\frac{(2n-1)90}{183}\leq10$$
> $$\Rightarrow n=10$$
> **So, the $2$ cars will meet $10$ times.**

**Solution:**

> The faster car covers $1080$ km in $10$ hours which is $12$ times the length of road and in each length, it will meet the other car exactly once - in opposite or the same direction. 
> **So, the $2$ cars will meet $12$ times.**

My approach neglects the possibility of the $2$ cars meeting while moving in the same direction at some point of time. Thus, wrong.

But the solution too could be wrong if both the cars, at some point of time, start in the same direction from one of the either ends of the road in which case the cars won't meet each other in that round, but the next round. How could the solution be sure that, that won't be the case??

---

Just to confirm what's the actual answer I drew the graph to know that the solution's answer is right and I was wrong:
[image]
One can see from the above graph that the $2$ graphs meet a total of $12$ times between $0$ and $600$ mins.

Also going a little further, at $1800$ mins, the 2 cars are at the same point and start moving in the same direction so obviously such a thing is possible.

Comment: I copied the question from MSE as there weren't getting answer. Here's the (useful) comments I posted there: $\\ $ the mystery that remains to be addressed is that while using the logic/formula that any meeting other than the first will happen after a time of 2d/t, I was taught that it would always work as long as ratio of speeds is less than 2 which is exactly the case in our problem. But it seems the theory I was told lacked some considerable substance or conditions as to really narrow down to when it would work and when not.

Comment: [contd] Secondly, the solution itself isn't standing on solid grounds as if it were 40 hours instead, the solution's approach would give us a wrong answer as at 1800 mins both the cars would be at the same end and will be moving in the same direction so there won't be any meeting for that 90 km stretch. $\\$ Here's the [post link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548693/number-of-meetings-of-2-cars-starting-from-opposite-ends-of-a-road).

Comment: You are correct to think that the solution has ignored(or hasn't bothered to mention) the possibility that the two cars meet at one of the ends. That's a condition that you can check quite easily in this case(since the numbers provided are calculation-friendly) by checking when the integral multiples of the times taken for a one way trip by the two cars become equal to each other for two cases, since they could end up together on either side of the road.

Comment: Other than that, you haven't made clear why you think your approach is correct.

Comment: @ReetJaiswal thanks a lot for addressing one of the concerns. So, perhaps I shouldn't have put it that way, I'll make an edit soon but basically the logic behind my approach is all standing on one of the assumptions it seems which is that the 2 cars forever meet each other while moving in the opposite direction and for some reasons it worked fantastically well for quite some questions. But I can't figure it out now that why it worked for those questions and isn't working in this one? Could it have something to do with the given distance's value or something else is amiss?

Comment: Your method will most definitely not work whenever there is a possibility that one car can overtake the other from behind. This can happen if the distance is short enough or the speed of one of the cars is significantly higher than the other's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139756/discussion-between-reet-jaiswal-and-inanimatebeing).